# Checking is array contains some elements of another returns incorrect result

Tags: javascript, arrays

The below code checks whether array1 or array2 contain hyphens under certain conditions. If they do, those hyphens are removed. I then compare the two arrays to check whether some elements in one array are contained in the other:

```
var array1 = ['banana-orange'];
var array2 = ['banana', 'orange'];

if (checkHyphen(array2) == true && checkHyphen(array1) == false) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        if (array2[i].includes('-')) {
            array2[i] = array2[i].replace('-', ' ').split(' ');
        }
    }
} else if (checkHyphen(array2) == false && checkHyphen(array1) == true) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if (array1[i].includes('-')) {
            array1[i] = array1[i].replace('-', ' ').split(' ');
        }
    }
}

function checkHyphen(a) {
    var finished = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].includes('-')) {
            finished = true;
        }
    }

    return finished;
}

console.log('array2 = ' + array2); //should match array1 - it does
console.log('array1 = ' + array1); //should match array2 - it does
console.log(array2.some(v => array1.includes(v)) == true); // returns false, should be true
```

If both arrays match, then clearly some() should return true, but it doesn't. How can I fix this?

Note: array1 and array2 DO NOT always have to match exactly, one or the other might have more values. I just need to test if at least one element exists in the other.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4fcywn8/)

Comment: btw, no need to check a boolean value against another boolean value, just take a `true` value or a `false` with a logical not `!`.

Comment: `array2[i] = array2[i].replace('-', ' ').split(' ');` creates a nested array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting elements of array to another array. So it create nested array. You should `flat()` them before checking.

```js
var array1 = ['banana-orange'];
var array2 = ['banana', 'orange'];

if (checkHyphen(array2) == true && checkHyphen(array1) == false) {
            for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
                if (array2[i].includes('-')) {
                    array2[i] = array2[i].replace('-',' ').split(' ');
                }               
            }                       
        } else if (checkHyphen(array2) == false && checkHyphen(array1) == true) { 
            for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
                if (array1[i].includes('-')) {
                    array1[i] = array1[i].replace('-',' ').split(' ');
                }
            }
        }       

function checkHyphen(a) {   
        var finished = false;

        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i].includes('-')) {
                finished = true;
            }               
        }

        return finished;
    }


array2 = array2.flat();
array1 = array1.flat();
console.log(array2.some(v => array1.includes(v)) == true);
```

You can use `JSON.stringify()` as alternate for `flat()`

```
array2 = String(array2).split(',');
array1 = String(array1).split(',');
```

Here is a short version of your code.

```js
var array1 = ['banana-orange'];
var array2 = ['banana', 'orange'];

if (checkHyphen(array1) && !checkHyphen(array2)) {
     array1 = array1.flatMap(x => x.split('-'))                
} else if (checkHyphen(array2) && !checkHyphen(array1)) { 
     array2 = array2.flatMap(x => x.split('-'))  
}       

function checkHyphen(a) {   
        return String(a).includes('-');
    }

console.log(array2.some(v => array1.includes(v)));
```

Comment: I'm getting array2.flat is not a function

Comment: @Sweepster Yes because `flat()` is not available  on every browser thats why in mentions second method. `JSON.stringify(array2).split(',')`

Comment: I'm using chrome though.

Comment: using JSON, I'm getting array2 = [["banana","orange"]] instead of array2 = ["banana","orange"]

Comment: @Sweepster Sorry my mistake use `String` instead of `JSON.stringify` i updated

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to check for hyphens and such, you should just define a function to process the individual input arrays, splitting each value on any hyphens and pushing the result onto a new array.

```js
const input1 = ['banana-orange', 'mango']
const input2 = ['banana', 'orange', 'apple-grape']
const input3 = ['mango']

function check(input1, input2) {
  const process = input => input.reduce((result, value) => (result.push(...value.split(/-+/g)), result), [])
  const processed = [input1, input2].map(input => process(input))
  return processed[0].some(value => processed[1].includes(value))
}

console.log(check(input1, input2))
console.log(check(input1, input3))
console.log(check(input2, input3))
```